# Plot NetCDF4 Monthly Average 3D Data Variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, np, netcdf4

I have code that looks like this

```
# combine multiple years of .nc files
mf = nc4.MFDataset("//porfiler03/gtdshare/IDL/wtypes/data/avgyears/slp*.nc")
sealpm = mf.variables['slp'][:,:]
print(mf)
print(mf.variables.keys()) # get all variable names
slpm = mf.variables['slp']
```

and I'm trying to contour plot a monthly average value for the variable "slpm" that has dimensions: 4380 x 73 x 144. The 1st dimension (4380 size) is in units of time that look like this when converted from numbers to date format:

```
timem = mf.variables['time']
time_convertm = nc4.num2date(timem[:], timem.units)
```

The output from "time_convertm" looks like this:

```
print(time_convertm)
[datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 6, 0)
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 12, 0) ...
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 6, 0)
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 12, 0)
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 18, 0)]
```

I have made a plot for one month (January 2017 shown below) using this code below:

```
#average for current month accounting for days and 4 hr chunks per day
cmonth = mf.variables['slp'][0:31*4][:][:] #Single year first 124 rows for January 2017
cmonthav = cmonth.mean(axis=0)
#-- draw coastlines, state and country boundaries, edge of map
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawstates()
map.drawcountries()
lons,lats= np.meshgrid(lon,lat) # for this dataset, longitude is 0 through 360, so you need to 
subtract 180 to properly display on map
x,y = map(lons,lats)
clevs = np.arange(960,1040,6)
cs = map.contour(x,y,cmonthav[:,:]/100.,clevs,cmap='jet',linewidths=1.)
```

Ultimately, I need a plot like the example shown BUT for an average of multiple January's in years 2017-2019 and not just a single year as shown. I cannot see how to average multiple Januarys' from 2017, 2018 and 2019. Thank you for your ideas!

[image: January 2017 Mean of Daily SLP]